# Pull data from excel, populate bookmark and saving as PDF with variable filename

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, mailmerge

I'm trying to pull a name from an excel sheet into a word doc that I have a template for and then save a new pdf for each row in the excel sheet.

I have almost got there. I can pull the data and it tries to save multiple copies of the same filename as a word doc.

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim X As Integer
Const strPath As String = "\desktop\auk\"
Dim strName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    strName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Client").Range.Text
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    X = 1

    Do Until ws.Range("A" & X) = ""

         Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

         objWord.Visible = True
         objWord.Documents.Open "\desktop\auk\Template.docx"
         With objWord.ActiveDocument
              .Bookmarks("Client").Range.Text = ws.Range("A" & X).Value

         End With
         If Not strName = "" Then
         strName = strName & ".pdf"
         ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                                           strPath & strName, _
                                           ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                           OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                           OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                           Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                           From:=1, to:=1, _
                                           Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                                           IncludeDocProps:=True, _
                                           KeepIRM:=True, _
                                           CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
                                           DocStructureTags:=True, _
                                           BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
                                           UseISO19005_1:=False
         End If
         Set objWord = Nothing

         X = X + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't save as a variable filename and doesn't try to save as PDF.

Comment: Could you remove On Error Resume Next and test it? I think that will suppress your errors

Comment: `Const strPath As String = "\\maplesandcalder.com\mfs\xauser\desktop\auk\"`, is that a legal way of declaring a variable? May need to put the `= ...` bit on a new line: `Const strPath as String / strPath = "..."`  Also, add `Debug.Print strPath & strName` before the `ExportAsFixedFormat` line and see if the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G in the VBEditor to show it) shows a path you expect.

Comment: I've added/changed to both your suggestions. I'm not receiving any errors shown and it it still loading the word version, then opening another word version saying the file is already open (as it's trying to open the same filename).